# Geting the current position in a UITextField

Tags: xamarin.ios

In C#/MonoTouch, I'd like to get the position of cursor in a UITextField as an integer offset from the start of the text contents. I'm stuck at what to do with a UITextPosition returned by tf.SelectedTextRange.start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this (t is your UITextField)

```
int index = t.GetOffsetFromPosition (t.BeginningOfDocument, t.SelectedTextRange.start);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks Jason.